# ShellExecuteEx & GetExitCodeProcess - Handle Invalid or Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, shellexecuteex

I'm trying to start an application and then monitor it until it closes. I'm using ShellExecuteEX and GetExitCodeProcess and having several problems.

The code below causes a segmentation fault when GetExitCodeProcess is Called. If I change shellInfo.fMask = NULL, it will not seg fault but I recieve an error saying Invalid Handle.

Notepad.exe does launch.

```
QString executeFile("notepad.exe");

// Conversion QString to LPCTSTR
wchar_t* tempEF = new wchar_t[executeFile.size()+1];
int tempEFTerminator = executeFile.toWCharArray(tempEF);
tempEF[tempEFTerminator] = 0;


LPDWORD exitCode = 0;
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shellInfo;

shellInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);

shellInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
shellInfo.hwnd = NULL;
shellInfo.lpVerb = NULL;

shellInfo.lpFile = tempEF;

shellInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
shellInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shellInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
shellInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

if(ShellExecuteEx(&shellInfo))
{
        if(!GetExitCodeProcess(shellInfo.hProcess, exitCode))
        {
            DWORD lastError = GetLastError();

            LPTSTR lpMsgBuf;

            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS , NULL, lastError, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);
            QString errorText = ("failed with error: " + QString::number(lastError) + QString::fromWCharArray(lpMsgBuf));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the problem is in `exitCode` argument.

MSND specifies it as `LPDWORD` that is pointer for `DWORD`. You should pass valid pointer to the function, so it could dereference it to save exit code here:

```
DWORD exitCode;
//....
if(!GetExitCodeProcess(shellInfo.hProcess, &exitCode))
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me, I dont understand why to use a DWORD over a LPDWORD.

Comment: You use `DWORD` vriable and pass _pointer_ to it to the function. So, you still pass `LPDWORD`, but that pointer points to your local variable. You could use `LPDWORD`, but then you'd have to write `LPDWORD exitCode = new DWORD();` and then `delete exitCode`, and it's just worse.